# Trouble with internal drives accessible from Plex

Tags: mount, permissions, drive

I just created my first Ubuntu desktop machine to run as my media server for Plex. I have a new SSD with the OS on it, two 1TB drives mirrored, and one 1.5TB drive. The problem I have is that I cannot get to any of the drives outside of the SSD, and even the SSD shows as not mounted in the file manager. I feel like I hosed something up.

Plex can't see the additional drives that are in /media/username/...`,

Netatalk can't see any directories in there either, but I can connect it to `/home/username/Documents` without a problem.

I don't even know what info to provide to allow people to help me. I ran `fdisk` to see if anything was up, and saw two warnings:

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/md127'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sde'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.
```

I installed GNU Parted and the drive mounted as `/dev/md127` (raid 1 drive) looked fine. Same for `/dev/sde`.

I have the SATA setup in BIOS to use AHCI for all but SATA ports 4 and 5 which are using IDE. The 1.5TB drive (`/dev/sda3`) is connected to port 5, and that's one of the drives I can connect to with file share, but not from any programs, but it's not one of the ones mentioned above in `fdisk`.

Comment: `fdisk` shows those warnings because it works on MBR drives (i.e. msdos partition table in gparted), and not GPT drives. You're looking for `parted` instead.

Comment: Could you provide the output of `mount` and `lsblk`?

Comment: I figured it out. I had not set permissions on the /media folder so that anyone other than the owner could see/use them. It's all good now. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Permissions were not set on the `/media` folder to allowed for Plex to see those drives. I updated the permissions and plex was able to read/write to those folders as expected.

Comment: what setting did you use?